# Ubuntu using wrong NIC for internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I have a machine running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  It is not permanently connected to a screen, and not within cable range of my router.  It uses a wireless connection for internet, and until recently, also for Synergy Software KVM switch, but that was frustrating and laggy.

I connected a cable directly between my laptop and the server and gave static IP addresses to the cable link, so that I can force the Synergy KVM to be more responsive and reliable, and this worked as expected.

Both my laptop and the Ubuntu machine have separate wireless connections to the Internet.  Since connecting the cable, the Ubuntu  machine cannot connect to the Internet, I suspect it wants to do so over the cable connection, but there is no route to the net that way.  How can I force it to use the wireless connection to connect to the Internet?

Comment: Please, give us output from command `route -n` and `ifconfig`, like edit on question. This output's will help us to help you. Basically you heve to change route from `eth` to `wless`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there is a right way and a wrong way, in my case, I think the solution was pure luck.  I deleted the gateway and DNS server information on the wired connection, disabled, and re-enabled both connectios, and viola, now Ubuntu uses the wireless as (default).

This alone did not fix the problem.  Ubuntu cannot effectively setup it's routing if both NIC's are in the same IP range.  The solution that eventually solved the problem was to put the LAN connection on a different IP range and subnet, while also not providing any DNS or gateway info on either side of the connection.

My setup used to be:

Eth Nic : IP 192.168.10.150 sm 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.10.1 DNS 192.168.10.1 
Wlan Nic: IP 192.168.10.109 sm 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.10.1 DNS 192.168.10.1

Then I changed it to be:

Eth Nic : IP 192.168.10.150 sm 255.255.255.0 gw 0.0.0.0 DNS 0.0.0.0 
Wlan Nic: IP 192.168.10.109 sm 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.10.1 DNS 192.168.10.1

This made the wlan NIC the default option, but the routing was still broken, so I changed it to be:

Eth Nic : IP 10.0.0.10 sm 255.0.0.0 gw 0.0.0.0 DNS 0.0.0.0 
Wlan Nic: IP 192.168.10.109 sm 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.10.1 DNS 192.168.10.1

And now it works like I initially wanted it to.

There is not /etc/network/interfaces content to add/display here, as I didn't touch that.  I did this using the Unity GUI tools.